# React-router: useRouteMatch doesn't return current url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am setting up the routing using react-router and the useRouteMatch hook. I can't load a component because the path is still different than the URL, but I wonder why? Because as you can see the URL in the browser tells me it should match, but then when I log the 'url' value from useRouteMatch() it still is one step behind.

[image]

**url in browser will be 'http://localhost:3000/compliance/546545/BeleggersProfiel/Profiel', yet when I log the 'url' value from useRouteMatch it will say http://localhost:3000/compliance/546545/BeleggersProfiel, so one step behind.**

**If I log the path below entered in the Route item, it is '/compliance/:compliance_id/BeleggersProfiel/:substep' so it should match the URL in the browser, but it doesn't. Somebody knows why the url is not up-to-date?**

```
export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/:substep',
    Component: SubSteps,
  },
];
function SubWizardRoutes({ steps, wizardRoutes = routes }) {
  const { push, location } = useHistory();
  const { url, path: basePath } = useRouteMatch();

  // when we entered the app and fetched the steps, proceed to the first step
  if (location.pathname === url && steps.length > 0) {
    push(`${url}/${steps[0].name}`);
  }

  return (
    <Switch>
      {wizardRoutes.map((route) => {
        const { Component, path } = route;
        return (
          <Route
            path={`${basePath}${path}`}
            render={({ ...rest }) => {
              return <Component steps={steps} {...rest} />;
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default SubWizardRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need `useRouteMatch` to `proceed the first step`.
Please try

```
const { substep } = useParams()
const isBeforeFirstStep = substep === undefined && steps.length > 0

if (isBeforeFirstStep) {
  const nextURL = `${url}/${steps[0].name}`
  push(nextURL)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was on holiday.

The problem is that even when the url has the last step in it (eg: http://localhost:3000/compliance/546545/BeleggersProfiel/Profiel). It doesn't show up when I use useParams(), so 'substep' is always undefined instead of 'Profiel'.